# Post revisions don't save or show up only for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

My website makes use of a number of custom post types as well as the traditional "posts" and "pages" types. For all "posts" and "pages" revisions show up as they should, with a history of edits visible, the option to compare posts, and so on. For all custom post types, I have no revision history at all. I've enabled revisions when defining each of these post types in functions.php, so on each of these post types I get a blank tab that says "Revisions" but does not display or collect any revisions data.

I'm at a loss for how to fix this and any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Does anyone know, perhaps, all of the places in a wordpress site that somehow affect or control the revisions feature? I get the sense that this is a very rare problem, so I'm curious about all of the places in my site that something may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I just wasted a lot of time figuring this out.

There are number of things a user should rule out first.

1. Deactivate any plugins and switch to a default theme like twenty-thirteen if the below items do not work.
2. To make sure that you don't have revisions turned off, be sure this does not exist in wp-config.php: `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);`
3. While on a page/post edit panel, click on "Screen Options" in the top right and look for a "Revisions" checkbox and make sure it is active.

That will usually fix most people's problems.

However. If there are no revisions for the post/page/custom-post-type you are looking at, the revisions option will not show up under Screen Options. You will know you have actual revisions on the current post if a revision count shows up in the right sidebar under "Publish" as the image below illustrates (Revisions: 2):

[image: There are revisions on this image]

If you don't see that, then clicking on "Screen Options" will not show "Revisions". So "Update" the post and then it should create a revision, and THEN you can click on Screen Options at the top and turn revisions on...

A little frustrating that it works that way, but hopefully that helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Jake's excellent answer, since I too just wasted a lot of time figuring this out.

1. **Edit and save the page/post twice**. Making a single edit didn't cause the **Revisions** checkbox to appear in my **Screen Options**. I had to edit and save the page twice. I'm not sure why, but it's worth trying if one edit doesn't make revisions appear. I suspect this could be related to the fact that the site had been created from another site's backup (via BackupBuddy).
2. **Confirm post type support**. I understand custom post types were working for you, but in case others experience this problem with custom post types, the custom post type must programmed to support revisions as discussed [in another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139031/enable-revisions-for-custom-post-type).

Comment: I know this is a super old post, but there are a couple tickets in trac now related to your first point about saving twice. Wanted to share for archival purposes: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42500 & https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44577