# Enable revisions for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

I have created a custom Post Type, and Registered it.

Can someone help me how to enable revisions to Custom Post type?

Comment: How did you register it? Using [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) or some plugin?

Comment: I though that revisions worked for all post types. Can someone confirm or deny that?

Comment: @s_ha_dum you need to enable it manually. There is no default set for "Revisions" in 'supports' in `register_post_type`. Only title and editor are set as default. Check the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @PieterGoosen : thanks. I kinda hate revisions and think they are poorly implemented so I don't deal with them much. :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

When you register your CPT, you need to manually add support for revisions. Only title and editor are set as defaults. Check out the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/). So if you need to enable revisions, you need to add it like this

`'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions' ),`

in your `$args = array()` when registering your CPT.

Just for info, here are the other arguments you can pass to 'supports'

```
'title'
'editor' (content)
'author'
'thumbnail' (featured image, current theme must also support post-thumbnails)
'excerpt'
'trackbacks'
'custom-fields'
'comments' (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
'revisions' (will store revisions)
'page-attributes' (menu order, hierarchical must be true to show Parent option)
'post-formats' add post formats, see Post Formats
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @jammypeach, it is important to know, the revision metabox will not show up until there are actually revisions for the post. If there are no revisions, the revision meta box will not show

Comment: I have place in Support array. Works fine.  Thanks, @pieter ..

Comment: @BhanuPrakash glad I could help. Just remember to tick my answer as accepted then.

Comment: Something to consider - the Revisions box won't appear after enabling Revisions on your CPT unless you make some changes and save a few times first. This threw me, I thought my code wasn't working but (of course) there were no revisions to display.

Comment: @jammypeach will update my answer. Thanks for that. Not many people might know it, did not even considered that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you @jammypeach I just spent an hour trying to diagnose what I thought was a problem with the custom post type def itself- that is certainly a key bit of info!

Comment: @nickpish dito!

Comment: If you have ACF with custom fields in your post type, addind the support revisions with enable the preview with those custom fields!!